# Offset issue moving columns from one WS to another

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, range, runtime-error

I'm simply trying to move some information from a column to another column on another sheet and using offset to get it to start on the row i need it to start on. trying to not use .copy or .cut or any of the sort.

```
with ws
    ecol = .cells(7,.columns,count).end(xltoleft).column
    .columns(ecol) = ws2.column("AB").Value2
end with
```

this works. just places it in the wrong area. so trying to use offset in anyway i'm getting 1004 error

```
   with ws
        ecol = .cells(7, .columns.count).end(xltoleft).column
        .columns(ecol).offset(7,0) = ws2.column("AB").Value2
    end with
```

Error 1004

```
   with ws
        ecol = .cells(7, .columns.count).end(xltoleft).column
        .columns(ecol).offset(7) = ws2.column("AB").Value2
    end with
```

Error 1004

```
   with ws
        ecol = .cells(7, .columns.count).end(xltoleft).column
        .columns(7, ecol) = ws2.column("AB").Value2
    end with
```

i suspect maybe it's because it's pulling the entire AB column from row 1 to 1mm+ and i just can't change the range.

either way i'd like some help tweaking this. i'm working with a dynamic range on ws2. i thought maybe i could use .end(xlup).row to find the bottom row and adjust the syntax but still getting the same error or i just don't know how to write it.

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
 with ws
        ecol = .cells(7, .columns.count).end(xltoleft).column + 1
        endC = ws.cells(ws.rows.count,"AB).end(xlup).row
        .Range(.Cells(7, ecol), .Cells(7 + endC - 1, ecol)) = ws2.Range("AB1:AB" & endC).Value
    end with
```

Comment: works like a charm thanks. so all this does is counts up to the bottom row, stops and grabs that range? is line 4 identifying the new range with a different/adjusted syntax and placing these cells there?

Comment: The left side range is the target cell(s), selecting the same number as the source cells.  The right side range is the source cell(s), endC is the row number of the last cell with values in the source column.

Answer (score 0):

I think you were right about the whole column transfer.  This code transfers as much of the column as possible.

```
With ws
        ecol = .Cells(7, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
        endRow = .Rows.Count
        .Range(.Cells(7, ecol), .Cells(endRow, ecol)) = ws2.Range("AB1:AB" & endRow - 6).Value
End With
```

you may want to restrict this to only transferring where there is data but thats up to you!

hope it helps